# Remove comments and escape characters from string sql query in python

Tags: python

Hi all I have a sql query as shown below with some comments and escape characters

Comments begin with **--** and escape character **\n** is used

comments can start with **--** and end with **--** as well, but end **--** is not mandatory

```
--Data Source for Tableau DQ Dashboard (Failure Summary) for IM \nWith DEP_DETAIL as\n(\n\nselect distinct D.SYS_NAME as SOR, A.YEAR_MONTH,A.SRC_INSTR_ID,C.data_element ,A.DATE_OF_BIRTH,A.STATUS_DESC,A.OD_REGE_OPT_CD,A.OD_REGE_OPT_CD,C.RULE_DESCRIPTION,A.PRINCIPAL_ENDING_BAL, SERVICING_COST_CENTER,A.PROD_LEVEL1_CD_DESC as level1_cd_desc\n,A.SRC_INSTR_OPEN_DT, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SRC_INSTR_OPEN_DT) as YEAR_INSTR_OPEN, D.SYS_NAME, E.DQ_CATG_NAME, A.LOB, B.PASS_IND\nfrom UMA_RBG_DQ.F_DQ_IM_ACCT A\nInner Join UMA_RBG_DQ.F_KDE_RESULT_DETAIL B\nON A.SRC_INSTR_ID = B.SRC_INSTR_ID\nAND A.YEAR_MONTH = B.YEAR_MONTH\n\nINNER JOIN UMA_RBG_DQ.D_RULE C\nON B.RULE_ID = C.RULE_ID\nAND C.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'\n\nInner Join UMA_RBG_DQ.D_SYSTEM D\nON C.SYSTEM_ID = D.SYSTEM_ID\nAND D.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'\n\nInner Join D_DQ_CATG E\nON C.DQ_CATG_ID = E.DQ_CATG_ID\nWHERE A.YEAR_MONTH >= to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-12),'YYYYMM')    -- 'Failure Trend' Dashboard shows failed and passed records for past 1 year, hence -12 from sysdate\n--AND C.RULE_ID <> 'RBG_DQ_1014'\n)\n\nSELECT\n    year_month, Data_Element, rule_description as rule, DQ_CATG_NAME as dq_dimension, level1_cd_desc,\n    SUM(CASE WHEN PASS_IND = 'N' THEN 1 END) AS failed_cnt,\n    SUM(CASE WHEN PASS_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS passed_cnt,\n    SUM(CASE WHEN PASS_IND = 'N' THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) AS failed_perc,\n    SUM(CASE WHEN PASS_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 END ) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) AS passed_perc\nFROM\n    DEP_DETAIL\nGROUP BY year_month, Data_Element, rule_description, DQ_CATG_NAME, level1_cd_desc
```

I want the end result with only sql query excluding comments and escape characters as shown below.

```
With DEP_DETAIL as (  select distinct D.SYS_NAME as SOR, A.YEAR_MONTH,A.SRC_INSTR_ID,C.data_element ,A.DATE_OF_BIRTH,A.STATUS_DESC,A.OD_REGE_OPT_CD,A.OD_REGE_OPT_CD,C.RULE_DESCRIPTION,A.PRINCIPAL_ENDING_BAL, SERVICING_COST_CENTER,A.PROD_LEVEL1_CD_DESC as level1_cd_desc ,A.SRC_INSTR_OPEN_DT, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SRC_INSTR_OPEN_DT) as YEAR_INSTR_OPEN, D.SYS_NAME, E.DQ_CATG_NAME, A.LOB, B.PASS_IND from UMA_RBG_DQ.F_DQ_IM_ACCT A Inner Join UMA_RBG_DQ.F_KDE_RESULT_DETAIL B ON A.SRC_INSTR_ID = B.SRC_INSTR_ID AND A.YEAR_MONTH = B.YEAR_MONTH  INNER JOIN UMA_RBG_DQ.D_RULE C ON B.RULE_ID = C.RULE_ID AND C.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'  Inner Join UMA_RBG_DQ.D_SYSTEM D ON C.SYSTEM_ID = D.SYSTEM_ID AND D.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'  Inner Join D_DQ_CATG E ON C.DQ_CATG_ID = E.DQ_CATG_ID WHERE A.YEAR_MONTH >= to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-12),'YYYYMM') AND C.RULE_ID <> 'RBG_DQ_1014' )  SELECT     year_month, Data_Element, rule_description as rule, DQ_CATG_NAME as dq_dimension, level1_cd_desc,     SUM(CASE WHEN PASS_IND = 'N' THEN 1 END) AS failed_cnt,     SUM(CASE WHEN PASS_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS passed_cnt,     SUM(CASE WHEN PASS_IND = 'N' THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) AS failed_perc,     SUM(CASE WHEN PASS_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 END ) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) AS passed_perc FROM     DEP_DETAIL GROUP BY year_month, Data_Element, rule_description, DQ_CATG_NAME, level1_cd_desc
```

How can I parse this sql query to get required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are looking to split your query into lines and only keep text on the left of any `--` occurrences:

```py
' '.join(part for line in query.split('\n') for part in line.split('--')[::2])
```

**UPDATE**:

Fixed to keep only odd positions after splitting by `--` (since comments can be nested)

Comment: AND C.RULE_ID <> 'RBG_DQ_1014' these are missed after comment in end result, Note comments can start with -- and end with -- as well, end -- is not mandatory

Comment: @sheetal `AND C.RULE_ID <> 'RBG_DQ_1014'` is on a line that starts with `--` so I don't actually get why it should be included in the result

Comment: as i mentioned ```--'Failure Trend' Dashboard shows failed and passed records for past 1 year, hence -12 from sysdate\n--``` is one comment , a comment can strart with -- and end with -- , but -- at end is optional in a comment, we can just have -- in beginning

Comment: that's fine this solution is ok with this

Comment: @rudolfovic still ```AND C.RULE_ID <> 'RBG_DQ_1014'``` is missing in result after updated solution is used

Comment: It should be missing because it appears on a new line right after a new set of `--`

Comment: Try `a--b-c\nd--e--f--g\n--x--y--z\nw` and you will see and it works

Comment: @rudolfovic its not a new set of ```--``` its end of comment ```--'Failure Trend' Dashboard shows failed and passed records for past 1 year, hence -12 from sysdate\n--``` as I mentioned earlier

Comment: this is really not clear, please add detailed examples to the question itself explaining exactly what rules you want to apply to the inputs